# How do you specify specific columns for a join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a column in a table with data from a column in a different table. The code I have is:

```
UPDATE extlinks
INNER JOIN sp_board using (title)
SET extlinks.board_id = sp_board.id
```

My question is as follows: Both tables are very large (millions of rows) and I figured I may be able to speed up the update if I only merge the necessary columns. How do I specify that the join should only include the columns in the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by how RDBMSs implement [Relational Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

In short, the server will only "materialize" as much as required. There is no poblem here, and it makes no sense in SQL to say "only include X columns in a join" - the columns can be thought of as not being included *unless* they are needed later (the common case is a SELECT that sends results to a client). In this case, only the `sp_board.id` column is actually required.

However, note Rocket Hazmat's comment - it revolves around materialization of records (not columns) - as it raises a very interesting question. I have no idea what the answer is.

Comment: What if you added `WHERE extlinks.board_id != sp_board.id`?  That wouldn't help?

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's a good question. I do not have an answer: I do not known this sort of situation is considered by query planners at all, especially in the case where both such columns are appropriately indexed.

Comment: To be pedantic, I don't think it's correct to say that "Relational Algebra" is what is taking care of this. More precisely: it's how RDBMSs optimize relational algebra.

Comment: @RocketHazmat , you don't want to prematurely optimize, especially not by making the query longer/more complex than it has to. I would run EXPLAIN (or whatever appropriate query analyzer you have) to see if the specific RDBMS you are using actually plans better with your modified query.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I'd upvote a million time if I could this could be the differnce between updating 3 records and updating 471,890,067. Always update only those records where there will be an actual change in the value of teh column

Comment: @HLGEM: That's what I was thinking.  Why update a column with itself?  But the database may be smart enough to realize that already, not sure.

Comment: @HLGEM I guess the questions stemming from that then are - Does the query planner already do this? If so, where/when? And, should it be expected to?

Comment: @hudson, that is not prematurely optimizing - in the first place he is looking to optimize, in the second place what he suggests is the way the query should normally be written , you do not plan to update fields that don't need updating especially when you have millions of records. Applying known performance ehnancers is smart not stupid. (and updating a few records vice all of them is a clear performance enhancer)

Comment: I can tell from audit logs that in SQL server at least, if you tell it to update the column it doesn;t check to see if the value is the same, it updates teh column. I believe most databases operate on this principle.